# Error calling macro from userform

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a userform to call a macro in a separate module when a button is clicked. I get the following error:   "Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

In troubleshooting I removed the arguments and changed the dummy macro I was calling to not take arguments, but I get the same error.

```
Public Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim Description As String
Dim Priority As String
If (checkCleared.Value = False) Then
MsgBox ("Please certify that all sensitive informationhas been removed and then submit")
Exit Sub
Else

'Description = formScreen.txtDesc.Value
'Priority = formScreen.comboPriority.Value

'Application.Run ThisOutlookSession!postScreenedEmail(Priority, Description)
Application.Run ThisOutlookSession!postScreenedEmail
End If
End Sub
```

In the separate module:

```
Public Sub postScreenedEmail() '(Priority As String, Description As String)
MsgBox ("postScreened")
'MsgBox ("Priority is: " & Priority & "    and Description is " & Description)
End Sub
```

I have tried other methods of calling the macro such as "Call postScreenedEmail()" but it cant see the macro then. My end goal is just to grab values from the userform and pass them to the other macro so they can be used with the API I am working with.

Edit: I may have mixed my terminology, this is the hierarchy I am working with (can't post pic with my rep).  That being said I tried to do the call with just `Application.Run "postScreenedEmail", Priority, Description` and it changed nothing

```
-Project1(VbaProject.OTM)
  -Microsoft Outlook Objects
  | ThisOutlookSession
  -Forms
  | formScreen
  |
  -Modules
    Module1
```

Comment: `In the separate module:` If it is in a module, why use `ThisOutlookSession`? Shouldn't it be `Application.Run "ModuleName!postScreenedEmail"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
call postScreenedEmail
```

instead of:

```
Application.Run ThisOutlookSession!postScreenedEmail
```

Since your sub is public, vba should be able to find it without the module reference.

If this works, add the reference again (makes your code more readable, especially for others, as ckuhn203 pointed out in the comments) and see if it breaks. If so, that's where the problem is.

---

EDIT:

---

Are you sure you're referencing the right module?

If I try:

```
-Project1(VbaProject.OTM)
  -Microsoft Outlook Objects
  | ThisOutlookSession
  -Modules
  | Module1
```

in Module1:

```
Sub jzz()
Debug.Print "test"
End Sub
```

and in ThisOutlookSession:

```
Sub test()
Call Module1.jzz
End Sub
```

it works. No problem. Using:

```
Application.Run Module1.jzz
```

instead of `Call` trows a compile error.

Even:

```
Sub test2()
Call ThisOutlookSession.test
End Sub
```

from Module1 works, without problems.

Can you run such small tests to try to get the references right?

Comment: Use the module reference! Think of the future dev who has to maintain the code.

Comment: Good point. I meant it to be for testing. I will add that in my answer.

Comment: I don't know what to make of it but it looks like from the userform I can call things from Module1, but not ThisOutlookSession. I've placed my code in module 1 and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... `Application.Run` takes a string for procedure name, and then comma-separated list of parameters/arguments:

`Application.Run "Procedure_Name", arg1, arg2, arg3`

So I think this should work:

`Application.Run "ThisOutlookSession!postScreenedEmail", Priority, Description`

Comment: Trying this throws:  Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.    I tried without the quotes and it throws error 450 again.